# ByteBuddy ElementMatcher based on method byte codes

Tags: java, byte-buddy

While ByteBuddy has a very nice API I am wondering if it fits my use case or if I should better stick to low level ASM.

What I would need is probably some sort of `ElementMatcher` that would return a match in case a method contains a certain, configurable byte code (e.g. `PUTSTATIC`). For all matching methods I would like to weave in additional code at the beginning of the method.

As a workaround I could of course scan the bytecode upfront using ASM, build up some meta data and then just use ByteBuddy to weave in the additional code depending on the analysis results (kind of what I'm doing with ASM now as well).

Doesn't seem nice though. Is there a shorter way to do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Byte Buddy operates with `TypeDescription`s and `MethodDescription`s which can either represent a loaded `Class` or `Method` or represents a parsed class file. Therefore, Byte Buddy has no good way to know what byte code is contained by a method.

For byte-code level operations, I generally recommend the usage of ASM which is exposed by Byte Buddy for this purpose by the `AsmVisitorWrapper` API.